# I need to handle NumberFormationException or NaN to BigDecimal

Tags: java, json, gson, bigdecimal, numberformatexception

I am getting below error,

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Infinite or NaN
```

When I am giving `Json request: {"sendAmt" : ""}` 
and storing that json object to some other Object using 
`gson.fromJson(inputStreamReader,msgClass)`

Note that sendAmt is a BigDecimal type.

I tried gson builder using registering TypeAdapters but I could not get that solved.

Comment: How do you expect `""` to be parsed into a `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried gson builder using `TypeAdapter` for `BigDecimal` data type. and it is working fine.

Here is my `TypeAdapter` code:

```
builder.registerTypeAdapter(BigDecimal.class, new TypeAdapter<BigDecimal>() {
  @Override
  public BigDecimal read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    JsonToken token = reader.peek();
    if (token == JsonToken.STRING) {
      String stringNum = reader.nextString();
      if (stringNum == null || stringNum.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return new BigDecimal(stringNum);
      }
    } else if(token == JsonToken.NUMBER) {
      return new BigDecimal(reader.nextInt());
    } else {
      reader.skipValue();
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void write(JsonWriter writer, BigDecimal num) throws IOException {
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried it,but it is showing this error to me:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Dangling name: bigdecimalVariable

Comment: Hey, I have updated the code according to your need.